# How to change parameter of objects in array depending on their similarity?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects:

```
const data = [
  { position: 1, name: "a", score: 9000 },
  { position: 2, name: "b", score: 8000 },
  { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: 4, name: "d", score: 6000 },
  { position: 5, name: "e", score: 6000 },
  { position: 6, name: "f", score: 6000 },
  { position: 7, name: "g", score: 4000 },
  { position: 8, name: "h", score: 3000 },
  { position: 9, name: "i", score: 2500 },
  { position: 10, name: "j", score: 2500 },
  { position: 11, name: "k", score: 1000 },
  { position: 12, name: "l", score: 1000 },
];
```

I'm trying to iterate through it using only simple JavaScript to get the following result:

```
const data = [
  { position: "1", name: "a", score: 9000 },
  { position: "2", name: "b", score: 8000 },
  { position: "3-6", name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: "3-6", name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: "3-6", name: "d", score: 6000 },
  { position: "3-6", name: "e", score: 6000 },
  { position: "3-6", name: "f", score: 6000 },
  { position: "7", name: "g", score: 4000 },
  { position: "8", name: "h", score: 3000 },
  { position: "9-10", name: "i", score: 2500 },
  { position: "9-10", name: "j", score: 2500 },
  { position: "11-12", name: "k", score: 1000 },
  { position: "11-12", name: "l", score: 1000 },
];
```

I've tried a lot of different approaches but nothing works, unfortunately. Any tips how to achieve  this? Thanks in advance.

This is probably the closest that I got:

```
function placement() {
  let repeat=0;
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let counter = 0;
    for (let j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if (data[i].score == data[j].score) {
        if(data[i].position==data[j].position){
          repeat++;
        }
        counter++;
      }
    }
    if (counter > 1) {
      let k;
      let start=data[i].position;
      for (k = i; k < i + counter-1; k++) {
        data[k].position =
          start + "-" + data[i + counter-1].position;
      }
      i=k;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear how the desired result relates to the input.

Comment: Can you share some of the things you have tried, perhaps the one where you got closest?

Comment: Your logic seems fragile at best. For the given data set the sorting of score and position aligns (inverse of each other, but both ordered) will this always be the case? Or is the position simply the index once sorted by score? (you have two at position 3, typo?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could group by `score` first and then add the position for each group.

```js
const
    data = [{ position: 1, name: "a", score: 9000 }, { position: 2, name: "b", score: 8000 }, { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 }, { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 }, { position: 4, name: "d", score: 6000 }, { position: 5, name: "e", score: 6000 }, { position: 6, name: "f", score: 6000 }, { position: 7, name: "g", score: 4000 }, { position: 8, name: "h", score: 3000 }, { position: 9, name: "i", score: 2500 }, { position: 10, name: "j", score: 2500 }, { position: 11, name: "k", score: 1000 }, { position: 12, name: "l", score: 1000 }],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
            if (!i || a[i - 1].score !== o.score) r.push([]);
            r[r.length - 1].push(o);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .flatMap(a => a.map((o, i, b) => b.length === 1
            ? o
            : { ...o, position: `${b[0].position}-${b[b.length - 1].position}` }
        ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the items in `data` are sorted by the score, i.e., the ranges are compressed into one instance per value, you can do the following:

1. Iterate over the array using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) having the `score` as the key, and its start and end `positions` as the value.
2. Then, using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over the array again, and for each item, set the position to the values saved in the Map:

```js
const data = [
  { position: 1, name: "a", score: 9000 },
  { position: 2, name: "b", score: 8000 },
  { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: 3, name: "c", score: 6000 },
  { position: 4, name: "d", score: 6000 },
  { position: 5, name: "e", score: 6000 },
  { position: 6, name: "f", score: 6000 },
  { position: 7, name: "g", score: 4000 },
  { position: 8, name: "h", score: 3000 },
  { position: 9, name: "i", score: 2500 },
  { position: 10, name: "j", score: 2500 },
  { position: 11, name: "k", score: 1000 },
  { position: 12, name: "l", score: 1000 },
];

const scoreMap = data.reduce((map, { position, score }) => {
  const { start } = map.get(score) || {};
  if(start) (map.get(score)).end = position;
  else map.set(score, { start: position });
  return map;  
}, new Map);

const res = data.map(e => { 
  const { start, end } = scoreMap.get(e.score);
  return { ...e, position: end ? `${start}-${end}` : `${start}` };
});

console.log(res);
```